# Are the File and Network async functions in C# truly non-blocking?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

My understanding is that there is a difference between asynchronous IO and truly non-blocking IO.

asynchronous blocking IO means that there is a thread waiting for the IO to finish. (It isn't the main thread, so the app stays responsive.) Because the thread is waiting, the CPU will put the thread to sleep and so it won't eat up processing power, but this still takes up a thread which assumedly uses some resources.

With truly non-blocking IO, when you wait for a File System or network request, the system actually frees up that thread to go do other things and somehow notifies your program once the request is completed. This saves you whatever resources a sleeping thread takes up.

Are C# functions like `System.IO.File.ReadAllBytesAsync` and `HttpClient.PostAsync` truly non-blocking?

Is there any way to tell which async functions in C# are non-blocking?

If the async functions are blocking (they cause a thread to wait) then it seems like there would be no advantage to using `async/await` even in a webserver that handles lots of requests because all the operations take up threads anyway.

Comment: You are calling methods and it depends on the way the method are implimented. There are three methods for implimenting Async method 1) Using a hardware interupt 2) Using timers to poll 3) Reading status bits inside a loop

Comment: @jdweng That's precisely what I'm asking about. Is it known which of those 3 methods these built-in C# functions use?

Comment: The Net Library uses a lot of Windows dlls.  Windows for stream classes (like reading writing files and I/O) mostly uses timers to move data (the timer tick process).

Comment: It is a strong runtime implementation detail, given that the OS must support activating a thread when an I/O request completes.  But on all mainstream ones you're likely to encounter (Windows, Linux, macOS) it is "truly non-blocking".

Comment: Not sure how work can get done without a thread....  At least in windows work has to be done on a thread one way or another.  Even when using a System.Timers.Timer the waiting has to be done in a "loop" somewhere.... As for Linux there is no such thing as a thread... As far as I know in Linux a thread is just a standard process.  Put in other words work, waiting has to always happen in some thread or process

Comment: The way async/await works a bit non deterministic... meaning it will  behave differently depending on a myriad of circumstances.  For example how long the task is taking or how "busy" the task is. Also a task is not a one to one match to a thread... for example you could control the parallelism and run many tasks on fewer threads.  Tasks are "pieces of work" to be done.  So for example 100 tasks not necessarily will fire up 100 threads.

Comment: Also we have to mention the physical limit of any system.  That only one task can be executed by one physical thread of the processor at any give moment. So this means that it depends on the number of physical cores.

Comment: Have you read [this](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html "There Is No Thread")?

Comment: Properly implemented `async` function is always truly non-blocking. `File.***Async` aren't properly implemented, test it before use. `HttpClient` is fine.

Comment: [In this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xGSabgBo-S8) Jeffrey Richter explains how does async non-blocking I/O work.